# Вывести изображение из админ панели Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, изображения

была настроена загрузка фото юзера в админ панель. В данном случае фото юзера загружается и отображается в профайле юзера. Мне нужно вывести это изображение на статьи которые опубликованы юзером. Есть переменная через которую я получаю собственно фотографию в профайл юзера `$profile_pic`. Вот так я получаю изображение в админ панель `<img id="shr-img" src="<?php echo !empty($profile_pic) ? $image[0] : ''; ?>" style="<?php echo  empty($profile_pic) ? 'display:none;' :'' ?> max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px;" />` Как обратиться к данной переменной и продублировать изображение на странице блога?

Comment: что вы записываете эту переменную $profile_pic?

Comment: function shr_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { $profile_pic = ($user!=='add-new-user') ? get_user_meta($user->ID, 'shr_pic', true): false; if( !empty($profile_pic) ){ $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $profile_pic, 'thumbnail' ); } ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если вы это делаете в цикле то можно получить id автора поста через get_the_author_meta не указывая вторым параметром ID пользователя. вне цикла нужно будет добавить этот параметр. Пример как вы можете получить ссылку на изображение

```
$post_author_avatar_id = get_user_meta( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ),'shr_pic', true );
$image_link = ! empty( $post_author_avatar_id ) ? wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_author_avatar_id, 'thumbnail' ) : [];
```

и потом вывести изображение

```
<img src="<?php echo ! empty( $image_link[0] ) ? $image_link[0] : ''; ?>">
```

подробнее о [get_the_author_meta](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_author_meta)